# JPA custom query with null values

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a custom query similar to this one

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "insert into devices (id, model_id) values " +
        "(:#{#device.id}, :#{#device.modelId}) " +
        "ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET (id, model_id) = " +
        "(:#{#device.id}, :#{#device.modelId}) ",
        nativeQuery = true)
void store(DeviceEntity device);
```

Both fields, id and model_id are of type UUID. I am running into issues when model_id is null, the insert fails in this case with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to uuid
```

Debug logs show this in the integration test

```
BasicBinder [BasicBinder.java:52] binding parameter [4] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
```

So I suppose that JPA is incorrectly casting NULL to a binary instead of correctly doing this (working case where I do not use the custom query - instead the repository.save() interface method in the crudrepository)

```
[BasicBinder.java:52] binding parameter [6] as [OTHER] - [null]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a customQuery in the service layer:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery([...])
.setParameter("modelId",new TypedParameterValue(PostgresUUIDType.INSTANCE, device.getModelId()))
```